# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float' using Ridge

Tags: python, numpy

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
rr = Ridge(alpha=.1)
```

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

I've tried downgrading but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Did you check the Ridge issue tracker?